# Java, print verbose exception data from a trycatch

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, verbose

I have a section of code that is, for some unknown reason, throwing an exception. I have this section of code in a try catch, as it writes to a file, so I need it like that. My problem is, I need a more verbose set of info about where exactly the exception is coming from, as atm I only have the fact that it is a NullPointerException, by doing a `System.out.println(e)` where e is the exception. How can I get more info about an exception when I am using a trycatch like this? I am after something like when an exception happens outside of a trycatch, and the command line goes beserk with a wall of text. I need that level of info. If anyone can help me, that'd be great.

Comment: Have you tried `e.printStackTrace();`

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.printStackTrace()` to get the stack trace.

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()` returns void, that won't work, it's just that on it's own, no S.O.P.